# Интеграция с facebook, авторизация по протоколу oauth

Tags: oauth, facebook

Первый раз пытаюсь сделать интеграцию с соц сетью. Все сделано по [документации](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/). В частности, как описано в Server-side Flow. (Код полностью скопирован, подставлены только свои переменные

```
$app_id = "YOUR_APP_ID";
$app_secret = "YOUR_APP_SECRET";
$my_url = "YOUR_URL";)
```

Нажимаю войти, ввожу логин и пароль, далее с фейсбука происходит обратный редирект с параметром сode. В адресной строке видно, что code пришел, но почему-то дальше ниче не работает - просто белый лист, в исходном коде - пусто, ни ошибок, ничего. Поэтому сложно понять, что не так. Может у хостера чего-то не хватает? Может кто сталкивался с подобным или делал авторизацию через oauth. Помогите, пожалуйста.

Comment: Очень простое и понятное решение это

[loginza.ru][1]


  [1]: http://loginza.ru/

Comment: Спасибо, про логинзу я знаю. Но хотелось как-то без нее.